# Recursion in lists

Tags: python, recursion

```
def obsah(myList):
    def recursion(myList,deep=1,result=(None)):
        if type(myList) == list:
            for i in range(len(myList)):
                if type(myList[i]) == list:
                    deep+=1
                    recursion(myList[i],deep,result)
                else:
                    result = (deep,myList[i])
                    break
        else:
            result = (0,myList)
        return result
    return recursion(myList)
```

this function is supposed to return the dept of recursion and the value of last element in list as tuple:

```
 obsah(['a'])
(1, 'a')
>>> obsah([[123]])
(2, 123)
>>> obsah([[[[[(3,7)]]]]])
(5, (3, 7))
>>> obsah(3.14)
(0, 3.14)
>>> obsah([[[1],2]])
(1, None)

instead the outputs are:

(1, 'a')
None
None
(0, 3.14)
None
```

After several times of testing i found that my temporary result is good but, the recursion is going one more time with default parameter(none), where is the problem ? shouldn't it end with that returns ?

Comment: Can you explain last testcase?

Comment: In particular, I think your last test case should be `(3, 1)`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one thing. If the list have more than one element, than it returns actual depth and None  // forgot because I do not implemented it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First, an aside:

Instead of writing this:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    myList[i]
```

Write this:

```
for element in myList:
```

Or, if necessary:

```
for i, element in enumerate(myList):
```

#### Now then, your code...

When we write a recursive function, we want to talk very explicitly about two types of cases. The base case, and the recursive case. We should be able to model them in our code as that style **very explicitly**.

In your code, you really don't follow that model. I can't really find the base case. Let's talk about the base cases:

1. If the object passed to the recursive function is not of type `list`, then we return the current depth and the object passed in.
2. If the list passed to the recursive function does not have a length of 1, then we return the current depth and `None`.

And our recursive case is to increment the depth and pass `myList[0]` to the recursive call.

So your code should be fairly straightforward:

```
def obsah(myList):
    return recursion(myList)

def recursion(myList, depth=0):
    # Base Case
    if type(myList) != list:
        return (depth, myList)

    # Another Base Case:
    if len(myList) != 1:
        return (depth, None)

    # Iterative case
    return recursion(myList[0], depth+1)

print obsah(['a'])
print obsah([[123]])
print obsah([[[[[(3,7)]]]]])
print obsah(3.14)
print obsah([[[1],2]])
```

Which outputs:

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 123)
(5, (3, 7))
(0, 3.14)
(1, None)
```

#### Remember:

The key thing here is to write down the base case(s) and the recursive case **before** you start writing actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution using while loop:

```
def obsah(nested):
    depth = 0
    while isinstance(nested, list) and len(nested) == 1:
        nested = nested[0]
        depth += 1
    return depth, None if isinstance(nested, list) else nested

print obsah(['a'])
print obsah([[123]])
print obsah([[[[[(3,7)]]]]])
print obsah(3.14)
print obsah([[[1],2]])
```

Prints:

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 123)
(5, (3, 7))
(0, 3.14)
(1, None)
```

This big if in return is purely for special case, that tells me it's something wrong either with approach or problem definition.